# Convert the data received by camera into a bitmap in android

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, android-bitmap

**What i am having:** i am using a camera to capture a image and i want to display it in a listview by passing bitmap to adapter in android

```
private void startCameraCapture() {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1024);
        }
    }



   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent myData) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
              if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1024) {

                    .............. mycode

           }

        }
```

**What i want to do** :: i want to convert the data i received as `myData` into a bitmap in android

Comment: what kind of data do you get back ?

Comment: What specific problem did you encounter?

Comment: @Blackbelt ..... Please see the edit .... i am launching the camera  and taking the image ........ now i need to get the image as bitmap and pass it into adapter as bitmap array

Comment: @CommonsWare ........as i described to blackbelt ... extending further.. Either i have to create file (get the location of it ) or need to use bitmap instead and pass into adapter .... which i am not able to do

Comment: the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) has a nice example

Answer (score 0):

**Convert byte[] to bitmap**

```
Bitmap bmp = myData.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```